# WP-PageNavi not working on category.php

Tags: categories, plugin-wp-pagenavi

It is working in another page I created where it shows all the posts, but not in `category.php`, where it shows only the posts of the specified category. It only shows the first page, the second onward it's blank (404). I tried a lot of "solutions" found in this site, like messing with permalink options, but no success.

It starts with:

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;?>
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'produtos', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'category_name' => $name, 'paged' => $paged); ?>
<?php query_posts($args); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

And ends with:

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<h3 style="color:#efefef;">Não há produtos com esses filtros.</h3>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: You should check with the plugin's support team about this. Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.